# Page Specific Navigation in WPF MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation

How do I implement page specific navigation in WPF using MVVM?  For example, if I have a "Settings" page and an "Accounts" page, each page has their own unique page specific navigation, but each navigation items are located in the same container in the app.  The navigation container is docked to the left hand side of the app window, and will never change, the navigation items however change depending on the page the user is on.  I have two approaches:

- Create a navigation view and view model for each different navigation for each page
- Create one navigation view and view model and dynamically add the necessary buttons accordingly based on whatever page the user is on

The second options seems better in my opinion, as it is more dynamic and only uses one view/view model, however I am not sure how to implement this.  I can easily code up a view and view model for one navigation container, but making it dynamic is a little trickier.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use DataTemplate and ContentControl, see [Jeremy Alles Blog](http://www.japf.fr/2009/03/thinking-with-mvvm-data-templates-contentcontrol/) for a good example

So to answer your question, I would create a view and view model for each.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I'll check out the blog

Answer (score 0):

Use [NavigationService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice(v=vs.110).aspx) and create the appropriate views and viewmodels.

Comment: Thanks!  Never heard of NavigationService before.  I'll check it out.

Comment: You are most welcome :) It has awesome features - you can pass parameters between pages, there's a stack that enables you to go back and other goodies.